# Artifactory anonymous pull working despite "anonymous access" being disabled?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

I have disabled "Anyonmous Access" in my Artifactory instance and removed all permissions from the "anonymous" user via the Artifactory web interface. Yet I am finding I can still pull artifacts anonymously from my `libs-release` repository via Gradle!? This is my project-level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // deliberately omitting the credentials { ... } block for the sake of experiment
            url 'https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release'
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest why the Gradle pull might be working despite the absence of the `credentials { ... }` block?

**Note:** If I navigate to `https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release` in a web browser when not logged into Artifactory it requests for me to log in in order to access the repository... as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. I had previously run the build with the `credentials { ... }` block and this was cached. So despite commenting out the `credentials { ... }` block Gradle was still using my Artifactory credentials from the previous build. On running the Gradle build with the `--refresh-dependencies` option I got the 401 (unauthorized) error that I was expecting.